# Putting on weight, gaining weight, getting fat

Tags: meaning, comparison

Which is the correct sentence or what is difference among the following sentences?

My friend is putting on weight.

My friend is gaining weight.

My friend is getting fat.

Answer (score 5):

Let me re-arrange the order of your sentences:

> My friend is *gaining weight*.

The most positive-to-neutral phrase. It simply states that the weight of the person you are talking about is increasing. This expression would be chosen in a medical context and is arguably the only one you could precede with "Finally" or "Thank god,...".

> My friend is *putting on weight*.

The colloquial version of the sentence above. Basically the same principles apply, but there is also room for the occasional "poking-a-flabby-pounch" irony or criticism: It depends on context whether it would be considered positive or negative.

> My friend is *getting fat*.

Not much room for interpretation here: Fat means overweight and - at least in western culture - that's considered negative. Of course you might be simply registering your concern about your friends health, but the expression is rather blunt.

Answer (score 1):

You are fat if you have too much weight because of too much flesh on your body.

If your friend is putting on weight or gaining weight, it means that his weight is on the increase. The only difference between these phrases is that the former is more colloquial and common than the latter that is a bit formal.

However, if he is gaining or putting on weight, it doesn't necessarily mean that he is getting fat. I agree to the comments of David Wallace "I am very skinny; I can gain weight without getting fat".

Answer (score -1):

Don't bother much!

> [putting on weight](http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/smoking/Pages/weightgain.aspx) is [gaining weight](http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/smoking/Pages/weightgain.aspx)

Also, you use *['getting fat'](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/technology-science/technology/belty-smart-belt-can-tell-4922648)* to mean that someone is gaining weight.

**BUT** socially, I think *'You are getting fat'* would be **a bit** offensive **over** other two options. That's my opinion though!

Note: I will not take you into the nuance of whether gaining weight is for good health *(as in some conditions such as recovering from tuberculosis or typhoid)*. If I do so, I'll digress here.

Comment: You might be *really* putting your foot in your mouth if you use "getting fat" and "gaining weight" synonymously!

Comment: -1. If I'm very skinny, I can gain weight without getting fat.

Comment: Probably you missed my *note*. It talks about it! @DavidWallace

Comment: I read it thanks.  It doesn't make your answer right.

Comment: @DavidWallace that's okay! As a doctor, I know that *gaining weight* does not happen without *getting fats in your body* but as I said, I won't get into it! And, I'm pretty sure the OP is *asking* in terms of someone getting bulky! :)

Comment: _I know that gaining weight does not happen without getting fats in your body._  2 thoughts: **1.** At least in the United States, we use _"gaining weight"_ for addition of fat OR for increase in muscle mass.  A professional basketball player might well _gain weight_ while _decreasing_ body fat.  **2.** Regardless of the previous _getting fat_ is not the same as _getting fats in the body._ Getting fat means that your body fat percentage has moved past average, and is heading towards obese - visible rolls, etc.  Going from scrawny to slim would be _gaining_ fat, not _getting_ fat.

Comment: @Adam Your athlete example is a good one. Professional boxers often gain weight to move up to a different weight division, and much of that weight is muscle not fat.

Answer (score -3):

1. My friend is putting on weight.
2. My friend is gaining weight.
3. My friend is getting fat.

The main words we need to look at in this form is that "putting", "gaining" and "getting" are all verbs (doing words). Since all three are doing words, they have no difference.

However, the first two statements end with "weight", while the last is "fat". These two can have different meanings, depending on the context you use them in. For example, the word "weight" can be used for human or non-human characteristics. The word "fat" is specific to things which can take the form of physical fat.

Now basing this on your three statements. You have started the sentence off with "My friend" therefore, the weight for your friend could be any type thing which can have weight, like muscle, fat, and bone. In your last sentence, you have said "fat". Therefore your friend is getting fat ONLY.

Comment: No.  In the phrase _getting fat_, the word _fat_ is an adjective describing body shape.  It's different from _fat_ the noun, denoting the oily substance that some of us have too much of in our bodies.  It is misleading to conflate these two definitions.  You could have loads of body fat, and still not be a fat shape.